# Inserting variable into mysql with php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to insert variable, which I'm getting from my form via ajax. I can `echo` my text and I can insert hard-coded text into my table, so I know that I can get my POST and insert things with my code correctly. The problem is a type of the value of my variable, I guess.

**Here is my php:**

```
parse_str($_POST['vals'], $data);
$message = $data['text'];
echo $message;
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments SET message = $message;");
```

(I also tried to use `mysql_real_escape_string` function, but it just resulted empty string.)

**My ajax query:**

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: url,
     data: {'vals' : $("#idForm").serialize()}, 
       success: function(data)
       {
          console.log(data);
          alert(data);  
       }
});
```

I'll be very thankful if someone helps me, cause I'm troubling with this so long although it looks rather simple.

Comment: Is there an error coming back from MySQL?  Check `mysql_error()`.

Comment: Start using quotes. Or prepared statements which is more secure.

Comment: Your query to database's wrong. Have you tried whenever execute the query before?

Comment: Also, at runtime, what's the actual SQL query being executed?  (Since your code is wide open to SQL injection, there's currently no telling what you're actually executing.  Could be full of syntax errors.)

Comment: mysql_error() doesn't throw me error. My query works, however I can't insert message. And it's probably very noobish, but how can I get my runtime logs? I've just started using mysql day ago, so I know nothing about such things. And I'll read about  prepared statements, thanks.

Comment: @K.Rice: Put the SQL query in a variable and echo it to the screen before executing it.  There's a good chance that there's a syntax error, which *would* be reported by `mysql_error()`.  How are you checking for the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add quote for query value. `$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments SET message = '$message';");`
Then try to remove vals variable quote for data ajax
  `data: {vals : $("#idForm").serialize()},`
Hopefully it will help you.

Comment: `$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments SET message = '$message';");` this helped, thank you!

Comment: You are wellcome K.Rice. Please to sign this answer as correct answer if this help.